# In general is it better to get critical, damage or health in bit dungeon

Tags: bit-dungeon

I always go for damage but recently I've been losing far short of my expectations, and I was pondering if it was better to get something else or to get small amounts of everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your preference and playstyle. There are no better or best stat build in Bit Dungeon.

If you want to play aggressively, you may want to boost up your Damage or Critical. But it requires you to dodge/block more attack to avoid losing health.

If you are playing defensively, you should build up Health. You will be safer but it could slow down your progress as well.

`What's the difference between Damage and Critical? Which is better mathematically?` – By [James Of Da Peach](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/68843/james-of-da-peach)

This is the information of stats in Bit Dungeon, provided by developer:

```
PotionFind - Increases chance to find potions from boxes etc..
LifeSteal - Steals .01 of the life steal per hit.
DeathStrike - Chance to instant kill normal enemies.
Chop - Chance to take off 25% of total life in one hit.
Cleave - Chance to do a double hit with normal attack Damage.
Proc - Chance to proc(Shoots your magic spell for free on hit).
Crit - Chance to do a Critical hit (Attack Damage + Critical Damage).
Defend - Chance to block all enemy Damage on hit.
RunSpeed - the movement speed of your character.
Attack - Normal hit Damage.
Critical - Critical hit Damage.
Armor - Reduces Damage by a percent.
Life - Increases max life.
```

Due to the formula of Critical hit (Attack Damage + Critical Damage), increasing Attack Damage seems to be a better choice because Attack Damage affects both normal attack and critical hit, while Critical only affects the latter.

There are also hidden stats bonus depending on the weapon type you are wearing:

```
Axe - +10 Chop
Hammer - +10 Proc
Blade - +10 Crit
Sword - +10 Cleave
Dagger - +10 Defend
Spear - Unknown
```

Comment: What's the difference between Damage and Critical? Which is better mathematically?

Comment: Please check the updated answer

Comment: Ok, thanks. (very) Useful information. +1 now, but I still like the idea of a mathematical explanation for which is better. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your skills.  I tend to beef up on health because I'm a little slow to dodge missiles and react and stuff.  I think if I had the reactions I did as a teen, I'd probably want to take criticals mostly.